# Convert number of days to English phrase expressing weeks and days

Tags: php, algorithm, time, data-conversion, phrase

I have a number of days to a date in the future but would like to know how many weeks and days it is. Also, noting that if its less than a week, then it simply returns the same number.

Is this possible?

e.g. `17` days would be `2 weeks and 3 days`

e.g. `4` days would be `4 days`

Comment: The modulo operator is not sufficient? How? `$x % 7` gives you the number of days which didn't fit into a whole week, and you can work out the number of weeks from there trivially. See also: The Fine Manual, over there: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: +1 for @Piskvor's suggestion, but if you ever need more than weeks, you might look into PHP's [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class.

Comment: Piskvor's right. Get the weeks by `round($x / 7)`, and then the days by `$x % 7`

Comment: @Nonym: `$weeks = round($x/7); $days = ($x%7)` won't do *quite* what you'd expect for `$x==13`. PHP has three different rounding functions for a good reason.

Comment: You're right, piskvor, but perhaps `$weeks = floor($x/7); $days = ($x%7)` would work, will it?

Comment: @Nonym: Quite so, as evidenced by the twenty-odd answers below ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
$days = 17;
$weeks = floor($days / 7);
$dayRemainder = $days % 7;
echo $days.'<br/>'.$weeks.'<br/>'.$dayRemainder;//add whatever logic you need here to get the display the way you want it.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$weeks = intval($days / 7);
$days = $days % 7;

if($weeks)
{
    printf("%d weeks", $weeks);
}
if($days)
{
    if($weeks)
    {
        printf(" and ");
    }
    printf("%d days", $days);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this should work

```
function getnumweeks(d) {
   totalDays = d;
   numWeeks = floor(d/7);
   if numWeeks != 0 {
      extraDays = totalDays % 7;
      return array(extraDays, numWeeks);
   } else {
      return array(totalDays, 0)
   }
}
```

Then you can call and use it as such:

```
ans = getnumweeks(17)

ans[0] <- Contains number of days
ans[1] <- Contains Number of Weeks
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Piskvor mentioned, you should use the modulo operator:

```
$weeks = $days/7;
$daysleft = $days%7;
```

Comment: If $x = 13; then $weeks == 1.8571428571429 and $daysleft == 6. Close, but no cigar.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say x is number of days, W is output value of weeks and D is output value of days remaining.

First do integer division

W = x / 7;

Then you take remainder:
D = x % 7;

Comment: `W` won't necessarily be an integer, due to the way PHP is weakly typed. You want a `floor()` around that.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I just write very general way, not exact PHP code ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$num_days = $databack30[days_to_next_event]; 
$weeks = floor($num_days/7); 
$days = $num_days % 7;

if($weeks>'0'){ $whenitis = ' in '.$weeks.' weeks and '.$days.' days'; }

else { $whenitis = ' in '.$days.' days'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For advanced coders, you can avoid declaring globally scoped variables by using a technique called [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403) to generate two unpacked arrays (either or both which may be empty) so that the `and` is only applied when necessary.

Pass the calculated weeks and days values into their respective anonymous functions, then conditionally populate the returned array with no element or an element containing the desired substring.

When the returned arrays are "unpacked" by `...`, empty arrays are completely omitted from the parent array.  This means that if one or both elements contain no substring, then the `and` will not be shown.

Test data: `$tests = [0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 28, 29, 30];`

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fV7RR))

```
echo implode(
         ' and ',
         [
             ...(fn($w) => $w ? ["$w week" . ($w === 1 ? '' : 's')] : [])(intdiv($days, 7)),
             ...(fn($d) => $d ? ["$d day" . ($d === 1 ? '' : 's')] : [])($days % 7)
         ]
     ) ?: '0 days';
```

---

For developers seeking a more intuitive coding style, declare more global variables and conditionally populate an array to implode. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KmAbt))

```
if (!$days) {
    echo '0 days';
} else {
    $w = intdiv($days, 7);
    if ($w) {
        echo "$w week" . ($w === 1 ? '' : 's');
    }
    $d = $days % 7;
    if ($d) {
        echo ($w ? ' and ' : '') . "$d day" . ($d === 1 ? '' : 's');
    }
}
```

---

Output (from either script):

```
0: 0 days
1: 1 day
2: 2 days
7: 1 week
8: 1 week and 1 day
9: 1 week and 2 days
28: 4 weeks
29: 4 weeks and 1 day
30: 4 weeks and 2 days
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to re-use this powerful function datediff:

http://www.addedbytes.com/lab/php-datediff-function/

as suggested in [php weeks between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028491/php-weeks-between-2-dates)

or taking inspiration from that code.