# How to list all loaded libraries and helpers in a CodeIgniter application?

Tags: php, class, load, codeigniter-3, helper

Is there a way to list all currently loaded libraries and helpers of a CodeIgniter instance?

I don't want to check them individually by iteratively calling `$this->load->is_loaded($item)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is best managed within CodeIgniteir Core itself. As it carefully checks the instances of the library property mapped to the Singleton Object, `CI_Controller`. These libraries & helpers are managed by a protected instance (`$_ci_classes` & `$_ci_helpers` respectively)

Otherwise you'll need to retro-fit what's been added to the Singleton Object. `CI_Controller` includes libraries, models & loaders to the shared instance of  `$this` - so it's tricky to identify what are loaded "libraries" or not.

```php
    /**
     * Example Controller
    **/
    class Home extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        
        /*
         * Fetch a List of Non-core Libraries loaded at $this.
         *
         * @var array $ci_libraries
         */
        public function list_of_libraries()
        {
            $ci_libraries = [];
            foreach( (array) get_object_vars( $this ) as $libraryName => $classObj )
            {
                //Is it a Core Class?
                $className = get_class( $classObj );
                if ( stripos( $className, "CI_" ) === false && 
                     stripos( $className, "MY_" ) === false )
                {
                    $ci_libraries[$libraryName] = $className;
                }
            }
            
            return $ci_libraries;
        }
        
        /*
         * Fetch a list of included Helper files & strip out the .php extension
         *
         * @var array $ci_helpers
         */
        public function list_of_helpers()
        {
            $ci_helpers = array_filter( array_map(function( $file ){
                return stripos( $file, "_helper.php" ) !== false ? 
                     basename( $file, ".php" ) : false;
            }, get_included_files() ));
            
            return $ci_helpers;
        }   
    }
```

Although as I mentioned previously - I do believe this is over-engineering for your original problem, `$this->load->is_loaded()` is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been able to implement the following in CodeIgniter 3.1.11 running on PHP 7.4.

```
var_export(
    (fn() => $this->_ci_classes)->call($this->load)
);
```

This is an "[Immediately Invoked Functional Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403)" which leverages the `call()` "[Magic Method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)" to enable access to the `protected` `_ci_classes` array.

If the property had `public` visibility, you'd be able to simply call `$this->load->_ci_classes`.

This will output an associative array of loaded libraries where the keys are the library object aliases and the values are the original library name.

You might see something like:

```
array (
  'benchmark' => 'Benchmark',
  'hooks' => 'Hooks',
  'config' => 'Config',
  'log' => 'Log',
  'utf8' => 'Utf8',
  'uri' => 'URI',
  'router' => 'Router',
  'output' => 'Output',
  'security' => 'Security',
  'input' => 'Input',
  'lang' => 'Lang',
  'loader' => 'Loader',
  'AuthLib' => 'Auth',
  'session' => 'Session',
  'mongo' => 'Mongo_db',
  'SomeLib1' => 'SomeLib',
  'SomeLib2' => 'SomeLib',
  'SomeLib3' => 'SomeLib',
)
```

Those last three entries would have been loaded like this:

```
$this->load->library('SomeLib', null, 'SomeLib1');
$this->load->library('SomeLib', null, 'SomeLib2');
$this->load->library('SomeLib', null, 'SomeLib3');
```

---

The same technique can be used to access the `protected` helpers array.

```
var_export(
    (fn() => $this->_ci_helpers)->call($this->load)
);
```

You'll get something like:

```
array (
  'auth_helper' => true,
  'badge_helper' => true,
  'email_helper' => true,
  'format_helper' => true,
  'url_helper' => true,
)
```

The `true` values are hardcoded when the helper is loaded and of no significant value.