# Implement array_search() functionality on the rows of a 2d array while requiring multiple associative matches in a row

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, associative

I want to search a key in a multidimensional array with two values in the condition.

I know how to search a multi-dimensional array with a single search condition:

```
$key = array_search($journee, array_column($data,'journee'));
```

but not more than that. Here is my array setup:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pseudo] => titi
            [journee] => 11
            [pts] => 3
        )

    ...
    [10] => Array
        (
            [pseudo] => test
            [journee] => 10
            [pts] => 6
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [pseudo] => test
            [journee] => 11
            [pts] => 4
        )

)
```

If I only put `11` in `array_search` and for `array_column` the key `journee`, it will return 0.

I want to add `pseudo` in the search condition too (the keys `journee` and `pseudo` should be searched for a specific values).

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: With one simple function it's not possible. With combination - it is.

Comment: so you want to search in json using both condition to be matched, `journee` and `pseudo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With one simple function it's not possible.

Here's a solution with **two**:

```
$search = ['pseudo' => 'test', 'journee' => 10];
$keys = array_keys(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function ($v) use ($search) { return $v['pseudo'] == $search['pseudo'] && $v['journee'] == $search['journee']; }
    )
);
$key = $keys[0];
```

But if you need to find **one** key only I advise to use `foreach` & `break`, because you don't have to iterate over all array of values (what will happen with using `array_filter`) and stop immediately when certain data is found:

```
$key = false;
$search = ['pseudo' => 'test', 'journee' => 10];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['pseudo'] == $search['pseudo'] && $v['journee'] == $search['journee']) {
        $key = $k;
        // key found - break the loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if he doesn't need to break after the first match, a simple loop is better. So the answer is reduced to _use a simple loop_ =)

Comment: Explain why simple loop is better.

Comment: 1) loop is more readable, 2) loop is a single construct, while the former solution uses a lambda and two function calls, all joined into a complicated expression; thus, loop should be more productive

Comment: Thanks, now OP can decide what to use)

Comment: Typo here most probably: `$return` ?

Comment: I like the both way (it learnt me how to use array_filter). I will use the most productive one (for each), thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

To enjoy the efficiency of a conditionally halted loop while excluding the temporary variables from the global scope, use an [Immediately Invoked Functional Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403). The qualifying row can be identified using `array_diff_assoc()` to check that all associative elements in the search array where matched in the given row. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/RApJd)

```
$search = ['pseudo' => 'test', 'journee' => 10];

var_export(
    (function($haystack, $needle) {
        foreach ($haystack as $i => $row) {
            if (!array_diff_assoc($needle, $row)) {
                return $i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    })($array, $search)
);
// output: 10
```