# Convert mixed number fraction (like '99 5/32') to float value

Tags: php, string, formatting, numeric, text-parsing

Data arrives as a string `'99 10/32'` or `'99 5/32'` or `'100 5/32'` or `'100 25/32'`, etc

I need it in decimal form so I have done this, but results are not always correct:

```
...
    $priceRaw = '99 5/32'; // ******also could be $priceRaw = 100 15/32, etc
    $priceFrac = (str_replace("/32","",substr($priceRaw, -5))/100);
    $priceFirst = (substr($priceRaw, 0, 3)*1);
    $value = $priceFirst+$priceFrac;
// original code that failed with one digit, e.g. 5/32
// $value=str_replace("/32.","",str_replace(" ",".0",$e->plaintext));
...
```

Comment: What's expected result?

Comment: 99.05 I then convert to a decimal by 
    Function convert32toDec($dprice){ 
     $y = (($dprice-intval($dprice))*100/32)+intval($dprice);
     return $y;
    }

Comment: `5/32` is not `.05`...

Comment: I just adjusted to -6 and that fixed it, so it is has something to do with the substr() but I can't replicate the problem on http://phptester.net/

Comment: Yes, that is why I wrote the convert32toDec() function above.

Comment: Shouldn't `99 5/32` be `99.15625`?

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by space to get parts

```
list($priceFirst, $priceFrac) = explode(' ', $priceRaw); 
$priceFrac = (str_replace("/32","",$priceFrac)/100);
echo $value = $priceFirst+$priceFrac;
```

Comment: I'm giving this one a try for the day, easiest to implement with legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll get hammered for `eval`, but works for all fractions.

Split on space and use the numbers in a calculation:

```
$priceRaw = '99 5/32';
list($num, $frac) = explode(' ', $priceRaw);
eval("\$result = $num + $frac;");
echo $result; // 99.15625
```

Or replace the space with `+` and calculate:

```
$calc = str_replace(' ', '+', $priceRaw);
eval("\$result = $calc;");
echo $result; // 99.15625
```

Then just `round` or `number_format` or whatever you need.   I may be missing something important as your math is funny.

Comment: No, you're right to be ashasmed of using `eval()`. :P

Comment: Not ashamed ;-)

Comment: I am trying to hack your interesting code by giving some `exec` or `system` calls in `$priceRaw`. But finally, this is hard to do, as it don't works. Any idea? Maybe because php7.2 now strong enough?

Comment: @Cryptopat use this as input `'99 1/2;eval(base64_decode(\'ZWNobyAiaW1hZ2luZSB0aGlzIGlzIG1hbGljaW91cyBjb2RlIGluc3RlYWQgb2YgYW4gZWNobyI7\'))'` https://3v4l.org/0s4nM

Comment: `sscanf($priceRaw, '%d %d/%d', $i, $a, $b); $result = $i + ($a / $b);`  would be much neater (for some definition of "neater") than using `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

Or we can go the regular expression route:

```
function convFrac($in) {
    if( preg_match('#^(\d+)\s+(\d+)/(\d+)$#', $in, $match) ) {
        $tmp = array_map('intval', array_slice($match, 1));
        return $tmp[0] + $tmp[1] / $tmp[2];
    }
    throw new \Exception("Badly formatted fraction.");
}

var_dump( convFrac('99 5/32') ); // float(99.15625)
```

Comment: I will take a look at it later today, easier to add the above for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Immediately Invoked Functional Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403) to parse the formatted string into its individual integer components, then perform the desired math.  I don't advise `eval()` if there is ANY other way.  My snippets are built with flexibility in mind so that `32` isn't a hardcoded/magic number. The numerator can even be larger than the denominator and the result will still be correct.  If any of the numbers in the input string might be float values, use `%f` instead of `%d`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/201GG))

```
$tests = [
    '99 10/32',
    '99 5/32',
    '100 5/32',
    '100 25/32',
    '4 20/5',
];

foreach ($tests as $priceRaw) {
    echo (fn($i, $n, $d) => $i + $n / $d)(...sscanf($priceRaw, '%d %d/%d')) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
99.3125
99.15625
100.15625
100.78125
8
```

The IIFE can be separated away as a variable with the same effect.

```
$func = fn($i, $n, $d) => $i + $n / $d;

foreach ($tests as $priceRaw) {
    echo $func(...sscanf($priceRaw, '%d %d/%d')) . "\n";
}
```

Or more old-skool/verbose:

```
function doMath($i, $n, $d) {
    return $i + $n / $d;
}

foreach ($tests as $priceRaw) {
    echo doMath(...sscanf($priceRaw, '%d %d/%d')) . "\n";
}
```