# Calculating reference number from formula

Tags: php, string, algorithm, math

How to turn this "reference number" formula in a working PHP code?

In my case:

Customer number is default 1, everytime/always.

Invoice number is determinated by user.

Verification number is calculated with formula:

The verification digit of the reference number is calculated by multiplying the digits that serve as its basis from right to left with weights of 7, 3, 1, 7, 3, 1... and summing up these products. The sum of the products is then subtracted from the next full ten, resulting in the verification digit. If the result is 10, the digit 0 is used instead.

Example of a Reference Number Calculation: Customer number: 1

Invoice number: 25 (invoice number has minimum 4 digits and if the inserted invoice number is smaller than 4 digits like 25 it needs zeros (0) added to it to equal that 4 digits. All zeros will be added left site. On this example 25 -> 0025. If the customer number is 4 digits like 1234 then that is the number)

Reference number base: 10025

5 -> 5 * 7 = 35

2 -> 2 * 3 = 6

0 -> 0 * 1 = 0

0 -> 0 * 7 = 0

1 -> 1 * 3 = 3

The sum of the products (35 + 6 + 0 + 0 + 3) is 44. The next full ten is 50. Therefore, the verification digit is 50 - 44 = 6.

The final reference number is: 100256

Here is what I have tryed:

```
<?php
$customerNumber = 1;
$invoiceNumber = 765;

$baseReferenceNumber = "{$customerNumber} 0 {$invoiceNumber}";

$entries = str_split(str_replace(' ', '', $baseReferenceNumber));
$sum = 0;

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $sum += $entry * (($sum % 2) + 1);
}

$totalSum = $sum;
$nextFullTen = ceil($totalSum / 10) * 10;
$checkNumber = $nextFullTen - $totalSum;

$finalReferenceNumber = "{$baseReferenceNumber} {$checkNumber}";

echo "Final Reference Number: {$finalReferenceNumber}";
?>
```

But this gives me result 107653, when the real answer is 1 07657

Answer (score 0):

After declaring the constant values and user input variables/constants, there are basically 5 subtasks.

1. Assemble the reference base string with padded zeros (your padding wasn't dynamic).
2. Iterate the digital characters from last to first (your iteration was from the front).
3. Perform the weighted arithmetic and sum the results (see my math with the modulus operator).
4. Round the total up to the nearest 10 and subtract the total from that number to generate the verification digit.
5. Append that result to the reference base.

If you favor classic loop structures, a `for()` loop will allow you to iterate characters from the back of the string. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/naOFg))

```
define('WEIGHTS', [7, 3, 1]);
define('WEIGHTS_COUNT', count(WEIGHTS));

$customerNumber = 1;
$invoiceNumber = 25;

$refBase = sprintf('%d%04d', $customerNumber, $invoiceNumber);

$weightedSum = 0;
for ($x = 0, $i = strlen($refBase) - 1; $i >=0; --$i, ++$x) {
    $weightedSum += $refBase[$i] * WEIGHTS[$x % WEIGHTS_COUNT];
}

echo $refBase . (ceil($weightedSum / 10) * 10 - $weightedSum);
```

If you prefer functional style syntax, you can use `array_reduce()` as the loop. The `static` declaration just allows the `$i` counter to be passed to subsequent iterations (otherwise it would be "forgotten"). ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ig8GS))

```
$refBase = sprintf('%d%04d', $customerNumber, $invoiceNumber);

$weightedSum = array_reduce(
                   array_reverse(str_split($refBase)),
                   function($result, $v) {
                       static $i;
                       $i ??= 0;
                       return $result + ($v * WEIGHTS[$i++ % WEIGHTS_COUNT]);
                   },   
                   0
               );

echo $refBase . (ceil($weightedSum / 10) * 10 - $weightedSum);
```

If you were hoping for a more hideous version, here it is.  You can smash all subtasks into a one-liner by inline-declaring `$refBase`, then concatening the result of an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403) which will consume `array_reduce()`'s retuned verification digit.  Keep your barfbag on-hand. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/q1CvF))

```
echo ($refBase = sprintf('%d%04d', $customerNumber, $invoiceNumber))
     . $verificationDigit = (
         fn($weightedSum) => (ceil($weightedSum / 10) * 10 - $weightedSum)
       )(array_reduce(
             str_split(strrev($refBase)),
             function($result, $v) {
                 static $i;
                 $i ??= 0;
                 return $result + ($v * WEIGHTS[$i++ % WEIGHTS_COUNT]);
             },   
             0
          )
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solution and I tried to make it very simple and easily understandable.

```
    $basis = [7, 3, 1, 7, 3, 1];
    $customer_number = 1;
    $invoice_number = 25;
    $padded_invoice_number = '';
    $padded_invoice_number = str_pad($invoice_number,4,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $reference_number_base = ( $customer_number . $padded_invoice_number);
    $reference_number_base_reversed = strrev($reference_number_base);
    $sum_of_the_products = 0;

    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($reference_number_base_reversed); $i++) { 
        $sum_of_the_products +=  (int) $reference_number_base_reversed[$i] * $basis[$i];
    }
    
    $next_full_ten = ceil($sum_of_the_products/10) * 10;
    $verification_digit = $next_full_ten - $sum_of_the_products;
    $final_reference_number  =  ($reference_number_base . $verification_digit);
```

Comment: This unexplained answer may not be robust enough in the long run. As the length of the customer number and invoice numbers grow, `$basis` will need to be ever longer.  This is the reason that the asker and I have implemented modulus-based array access as part of the algorithm.