# PHP - Date equation for showing a daily menu every three weeks

Tags: php, date, math

So I'm making a website for this pizzeria.

In the past I made a simple window that pops up Monday-Friday & Between 11.30am-02:00pm which is simple enough.

But now I've had a request to do the same thing, but instead of having a single "Lunch Buffe Ongoing!" box, the client want's a daily menu (different menu every day, which is also easy enough), but he has 3 different daily menus alternating every week.

So here's an example:
Week 1 Menu:
Monday: w1m1
Tuesday: w1m2
..

Week 2 Menu:
Monday: w2m1
Tuesday: w2m2

So my question is:
**Is there a PHP function / equation for calculating "is it the first, second or third" week from a specified starting date**

Edit (Not duplicate because):
This isn't a duplicate of [PHP get number of week for month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853380/php-get-number-of-week-for-month) because I'm not asking for the week number, I'm asking what week this is alternating with 3

## Answer:

```
<?php
    function menuNumber($now) {
        $then = '26/05/2014';
        $first = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $then);
        $second = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $now);
        $calculated = (floor($first->diff($second)->days/7) % 3) + 1;
        return $calculated;
    }
    echo "Menu Number " . menuNumber(date("d/m/Y")); // Menu Number 1
?>
```

Help From:
[php weeks between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028491/php-weeks-between-2-dates)

Comment: There are SQL functions to do that.  Do you have a database connection?

Comment: To the person that posted the "same question", no it's not.. I'm asking "is this week 1, 2 or 3" since the starting week (which I'll specify)

Yes @wallyk , I do :)

Comment: @JohnConde Can you please unmark this as a duplicate so I can post my answer to anyone that wishes to see this in future, in the "Edit" section I explained why it wasn't a duplicate

Comment: @wallyk Would you also suggest using MS-Excel if there exists such a  macro?

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch:  probably not, unless there was reason to suspect his PHP installation was already linked to Excel.  I think I have a few PHP programs which do not connect to MySQL, but all the rest do.

Comment: @RichardMuthwill "week of year" and modulo are your friends. Both available in PHP only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP

```
<?php
    function menuNumber($now) {
        $then = '26/05/2014';
        $first = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $then);
        $second = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $now);
        $calculated = (floor($first->diff($second)->days/7) % 3) + 1;
        return $calculated;
    }
    echo "Menu Number " . menuNumber(date("d/m/Y")); // Menu Number 1
?>
```

Help From: [PHP weeks between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028491/php-weeks-between-2-dates)