# php - number of calendaristic weeks betwen 2 dates

Tags: php, date

I want to measure the number of weeks between 2 dates.

For example between 13-12-2015 and 14-12-2015 the function should return 2 weeks, because first date it's Sunday and second date it's Monday, so it's 2 different weeks.

This has to work with different year dates, and here is what I tried:

```
$d1= new \DateTime('2014-10-14');
$d2= new \DateTime('2015-12-15');
echo $d2->diff($d1)/7;
```

The result is 61, but in reality it should be 62.

Any tips?

Comment: 427 days / 7 = 61 ? Your problem is that should be 62?

Comment: well between 13-12-2015 and 14-12-2015 is only 1 day difference, but they are 2 different weeks, so your afrimation is not valid: 1/7 =2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php weeks between 2 dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028491/php-weeks-between-2-dates)

Comment: no, that's not what i want

Answer (score 0):

```
   echo datediff('ww', '9 July 2003', '4 March 2004', false);
```

datediff function you can find in following link...

[Click here to see Week Difference function link](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/code/php-datediff-function/)

Comment: it still returns 61, it calculates the days, not the actual weeks.

Comment: Answer fully duplicated 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028491/php-weeks-between-2-dates

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov yaaa bro... I accept... please vote it down. if you want. :P

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it on my own finally, here is the code:

```
$a1 = date('W', strtotime('2015-12-13'));
$a2 = date('Y', strtotime('2015-12-13'));

$b1 = date('W', strtotime('2015-12-14'));
$b2 = date('Y', strtotime('2015-12-14'));

echo $b2 * 52 + $b1 - $a2 * 52 - $a1 +1;
```

Result:

```
2
```

P.S. I don't know why everybody is spamming that is duplicate, when obviously it isn't.